# Trouble with one-to-many relationship in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, coffeescript

I'm brand new to ember. I get the basic concepts of the framework and the naming conventions, etc. I'm trying to learn how to do relationship modeling and the docs aren't helping out too much. For the example, I'm building a simple blog app with comments (just a proof-of-concept for myself). I want to display the comments on each post page; however, I'm getting a strange error when I try to render the comments in an `{{each}}` block This is the relevant code (coffeescript for readability):

```
// file: models/post.js

BlogApp.Post = DS.Model.extend
    title: DS.attr 'string'
    contents: DS.attr 'string'
    comments: DS.hasMany 'comment'

BlogApp.Post.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'My first post',
        contents: "Lorem ipsum dolor blah blah blah",
        comments: [1, 3]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Heating up',
        contents: "I'm really getting the hang of this blogging thing.",
        comments: [2, 4]
    }
]
```

Similarly for the comments:

```
// file: models/comment.js

BlogApp.Comment = DS.Model.extend
    post: DS.belongsTo 'post'
    text: DS.attr 'string'

BlogApp.Comment.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id: 1,
        text: "Haha yes!"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: "Alrighty then"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: "Eh, I don't agree"
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        text: "This is great!"
    }
]
```

The routes seem to be set up correctly.

```
// file: router.js

BlogApp.Router.map ->
    @resource 'posts'
    @resource 'post', path: 'post/:post_id', ->
        @resource 'comments'

BlogApp.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
    model: ->
        @store.find 'post'
```

Finally, the template (this is where the problem is occurring):

```
// file: templates/post/index.hbs

<h3>{{title}}</h3>
<p>{{contents}}</p>

<hr>

<h4>Comments</h4>
<ul>
    {{#each comments}}
        <li>hi</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

I am getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined`. If I take out the each block, everything works correctly so I know it has something to do with the way the comments are being retrieved from the data store or how they are being passed by the controller.

If I take a look at the ember chrome extension, I can see the comments in the data tab, but the "text" property is undefined. Any help would be appreciated. I feel as if I have a small piece missing but I can't figure it out given my limited knowledge of ember thus far.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you forget setting the adapter?

`BlogApp.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter;`
 and {async: true} in relationship?
`comments: DS.hasMany 'comment', {async: true}`

Comment: Thanks! I had the adapter right but it was the async property in the options hash that got me. Could you explain why that was causing the problem? I'm assuming the default value is false but why does that make a difference if I'm using a fixture?